# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "autobús" y "autocar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sustantivos, diferencias-entre-palabras, transporte

En la zona donde vivo es bastante común decir *autobús* y *autocar* de forma indistinta. El otro día lo comentaba con no sé quién y me dijo que uno de ellos es para trayectos cortos... y la respuesta me medio convenció. Impulsado por las ganas de ampliar horizontes, me dirigí al DLE y vi que:

> [**autobús**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4RA0JzM)
>   `Del fr.`*`autobus`*`, de`*`auto`*`'auto²' y`*`omnibus`*`'ómnibus'.`
>
> 1. m. Vehículo automóvil de transporte público y trayecto fijo que se emplea habitualmente en el servicio urbano.
> 2. m. autocar.

Y luego

> [**autocar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4RK9f0l)
>   `Del fr.`*`autocar`*`, de`*`auto`*`'auto²' y el ingl.`*`car`*`'coche¹'.`
>
> 1. m. Vehículo automóvil de gran capacidad concebido para el transporte de personas, que generalmente realiza largos recorridos por carretera.

Donde [*auto²*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4QuGzfX) es automóvil.

En base a estas definiciones, la explicación que me dieron parece satisfactoria, si bien el hecho de que la segunda acepción de *autobús* sea *autocar* me hace pensar en un cierto deslizamiento hacia la adopción de ambas palabras como sinónimas directas.

Mirando un poco para atrás, resulta que *autocar* solo entró en los diccionarios en 1970 (*Academia Usual*) como *ómnibus automóvil*, momento en el cual definían el *autobús* como lo mismo con la coletilla de *que se emplea en el servicio urbano*. *Autobús* es algo más vieja y ya aparece en 1927 (*Academia Manual*).

Por todo ello, ¿cómo se usan actualmente estas palabras? ¿Cuál es su tendencia? ¿Se puede asumir una tendencia a ser sinónimas?

Comment: ¿Te interesa específicamente España, o incluso tu región en particular?  Si es así, sugiero que así le etiquetees.  // A manera de paréntesis: En México, el *urbano* va dentro de la ciudad, y el autobús va de una ciudad a otra.  Y el autobús puede ser *de primera [clase]*, *de segunda [clase]*, o ... puede ser *el totolero*, es decir que puedes subirte con gallinas (vivas) o incluso guajolotes.  En algunas ciudades hay vanes también, y no recuerdo cómo se les llama.

Comment: Curioso, parece que _autobús_ se usa más para el servicio urbano y _autocar_ para los desplazamientos entre ciudades. En todo caso, comentar que la verdad es que aquí en Andalucía la palabra _autocar_ no la suelo usar ni oír mucho (sí se usa más en plan técnico), lo que suele decir la gente es _autobús_ con independencia de si es urbano o no. Aquí decimos que vamos a ir a Madrid en autobús, no en autocar. Y las excursiones del colegio también se hacen en autobús, aunque sean diferentes de los de línea.

Comment: @aparente001 me interesa ver cómo se usa en general, de ahí que añadiera la etiqueta [tag:diferencias-regionales]. Comento el uso en España por el hecho de que es donde vivo actualmente y así lo oí, pero no me interesa especialmente en un lugar concreto.

Comment: My granma exactly uses like that; _autocar_ for intercity coaches, _autobús_ for the local mass transit.

Comment: Esta misma diferencia existe todavia en francês, de donde vinieron las palabras. Claro, en relación a los usos en España.

Answer (score 1):

**México**: no se usa *autocar*.
**Colombia**: no se usa *autocar*.

**España**:

Answer (score 0):

En **Colombia** se usa genéricamente la palabra **bus** para referirse tanto al vehículo de ruta urbana como al que hace ruta entre 2 ciudades.

Se usan adjetivos cuando se requiere diferenciarlos:
**Bus urbano** para el que hace recorridos dentre de una ciudad o población.
**Bus intermunicipal** al que realiza recorrido entre 2 ciudades o más; para estos también se usa la palabra **flota** y de hecho muchas empresas tiene esa palabra en su nombre como **Flota La Macarena**, o **Flota Valle de Tenza**.

No se usa la palabra **autobus** y la palabra **autocar** es inexistente.

Answer (score 0):

El autobús por ser un transporte público para dentro de la ciudad van personas sentadas y otras de pie.
Mientras que el autocar concebido para el transporte entre provincias solamente pueden ir personas sentadas con el cinturón de seguridad.
Si todas las plazas son asientos es un autocar y si hay plazas para ir de pie e ir sentados es un autobús.

Comment: Podría ser útil también mencionar cuál país tiene este uso específico